# Google map markers render randomly

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, asynchronous

I have a feature on my site to display a google map of a carpool for a particular hike.  There are 3 things that should appear on the map:

1. Destination spot
2. Little pictures of cars to indicate drivers
3. Happy faces to indicate people that need a ride.

What happens is that the happy faces and car icons render at random times. Sometimes only cars appear and sometimes only the happy faces. I am wondering if I am doing something wrong in my AJAX.

Here is an example page.  See mid-column on the right side for the carpool map:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/scheduled_hike.php?hike_id=169

In my `<body>` tag I am doing this:

```
<body onload="initialize( <?php echo $hike_id; ?> ); placeHikeStartMarker( <?php echo $hike_id; ?> );  placeCarpoolPassengersMarkers( <?php echo $hike_id; ?> ); placeCarpoolDriversMarkers( <?php echo $hike_id; ?> );">
```

Is there anything in the nature of AJAX of google maps that would cause this sort of inconsistency since the calls are a-synchronous?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a problem with the Google Maps API as I've never seen anything like this.

I'm more likely to suspect a problem with your server or code.

It looks like your server is returning the results fine (in the AJAX requests) - so it isn't overloaded or timing out.

Are you adding markers to the same array, and possibly over-writing them?